# How to stretch a texture towards the center of a 3D object

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, procedural, shader-nodes

I'm trying to scale a texture towards the center of a 3D object.
I've seen some solutions for 2D objects like planes, but it doesn't work in 3 dimensions. How to do this?

[image]

Comment: practically, do you want to use an image texture or something with shaders that radially runs along the object?

Comment: Something with shaders, like a procedural texture (e.g. a noise) and scale the texture infinitely towards the center